# where am i going wrong with try/except statements

Tags: python

sorry if i have worded anything wrong,

i am trying to open all files in a folder but i cant filter out the files from the folders, so i used try/except statements so that if it opens a folder and has an error (in my case PermissionError) then it skips it, but now it is saying "Exception has occurred: Permission Error" with an except statement right below it saying "except PermissionError:"

this is my code

```
from pathlib import Path as user
import os

path = str(f"{user.home()}\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft")

mc_dir = os.listdir(path)
for entry in mc_dir:
    try:
        f = open(f"{path}\\{entry}", "r")
    except PermissionError:
        ()
    finally:
        f.close()
```

and line 9 raises the error

```
Exception has occurred: PermissionError
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\_____\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\.fabric'
  File "C:\Users\_____\_________\______\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    f = open(f"{path}\\{entry}", "r")
```

[image: pic of the error]

does anyone know why it does this and/or how i can fix this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce (although my case isn't exactly the same obviously). Did you accidentally import a `PermissionError` from a library?

Comment: This shouldn't happen.  Maybe it's a special feature of whatever IDE you're using there?

Comment: If `open` fails then your finally block will raise another exception, because `f` will not exist.

Comment: This error is raised when you run it?

Comment: VSCode will do this if you are running in debug with "Raised Exceptions" ticked.